# Windowless Taskbar Button

Tags: c#, windows, taskbar, windows-api-code-pack

I would like to create a windowless taskbar button, just like Windows Live Messenger does it:

[image: Windows live messenger taskbar icon]

How can I do that in C#? The Windows API Code pack looks helpful, but I haven't found any way to create a taskbar button with it.

Comment: Are you specifically saying that it shows their profile image and then even has an email button on it?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Creating the button is not my problem, that's pretty easy with the Windows API Code Pack. I just don't know how I can create the icon in the taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden window (CreateWindow and then ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE). This is will make the taskbar show an icon.

Then use the ITaskbarList, ITaskbarList2, ITaskbarList3, ITaskbarList4 APIs to set a different thumbnail for the window.